HTML SVG Reduce Path Circle Size
I have a svg grey circle and a red path that follows the circle/overlays.
Does anyone know how to shrink the red circle so that it 100% covers the grey circle?
I cannot for the life of me work out how to shrink the red circle radius.... I know with the circle I can change r="30" to make it bigger or smaller, but for the path, I am stuck.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwko5emv/
Thank you


 .base-timer {
   position: relative;
   background-color: pink;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
 }
 .base-timer__circle {
   fill: none;
   stroke: none;
 }
 .base-timer__path-elapsed {
   stroke-width: 14%;
   stroke: grey;
 }
 .base-timer__path-remaining {
   stroke-width: 14%;
   stroke-linecap: round;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform-origin: center;
   transition: 1s linear all;
   fill-rule: nonzero;
   stroke: currentColor;
 }
<div class="base-timer">
   <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g class="base-timer__circle">
         <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
         <path
            id="base-timer-path-remaining"
            stroke-dasharray={circleDasharray}
            style="color: red;"
            class="base-timer__path-remaining"
            d=" M 50, 50
            m -45, 0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0"
            >
         </path>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>



Tried to play around with the d= variables but could not shrink the circle.

What is the end goal? Why not have two circles now that they should overlap?

You can edit a single d-path in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Note: if you don't want to/can't change the path, then change the circle

By default <circle> elements start at "3'o clock" (or 0 degree) and are drawn in a clockwise direction.
The correct path data reproducing the <circle> element – using relative commands with the same starting point would be:
M 80 50
a 30 30 0  0 1 -60 0
a 30 30 0  0 1  60 0



circle{
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:2px;
}

path{
  stroke:green;
}

circle,
path {
  marker-start: url(#markerStart);
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
<!--
M: cx+r = 80 | cy 
a: rx=r = 30 | ry=r = 30 | x-axis-rotation=0 | large-arc-flag=0/1 | sweep-flag = 1 (clockwise) | x=-r*2 | y=0
a: rx=r = 30 | ry=r = 30 | x-axis-rotation=0 | large-arc-flag=0/1 | sweep-flag = 1 (clockwise) | x=r*2 | y=0
-->
         <path
            d="M 80 50
               a 30 30 0  0 1 -60 0
               a 30 30 0  0 1  60 0"
            >
         </path>
   </svg>
   
  <!-- markers to show commands -->
  <svg id="svgMarkers" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute; z-index:-1;float:left;">
    <defs>
      <marker id="markerStart" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="green"></circle>
        </marker>
    </defs>
  </svg>



See SVG spec "9.3.8. The elliptical arc curve commands"
M: cx+r = 80 | cy 
a: rx=r = 30 | ry=r = 30 | x-axis-rotation=0 | large-arc-flag=0/1 | sweep-flag = 1 (clockwise) | x=-r*2 | y=0
a: rx=r = 30 | ry=r = 30 | x-axis-rotation=0 | large-arc-flag=0/1 | sweep-flag = 1 (clockwise) | x=r*2 | y=0

We're basically drawing half circles with each a command.

from the right-center to the left-center coordinates of the circle
and a closing semi-circle returning to the starting point.



.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 14%;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 14%;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: currentColor;
}
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g class="base-timer__circle">
         <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
         <path
            id="base-timer-path-remaining"
            stroke-dasharray={circleDasharray}
            style="color: red;"
            class="base-timer__path-remaining"
            d="M 80 50
               a 30 30 0  0 1 -60 0
               a 30 30 0  0 1  60 0"
            >
         </path>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>



Since we're using relative commands you could easily apply shifts/offsets by adjusting the M command - e.g if you're moving the <circle> element to another position.
In case of perfect circles you can even further simplify the syntax by omitting the exact rx/ry values
M 80 50
a 1 1 0  0 1 -60 0
a 1 1 0  0 1  60 0

The renderer will auto-adjust the too small radii according to the final on-path coordinates (6. and 7. value)


circle{
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:2px;
}

path{
  stroke:green;
}
   <svg  viewBox="0 0 300 300" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <circle  cx="120" cy="90" r="20"></circle>
         <path
            d="M 140 90
               a 1 1 0  0 1 -40 0
               a 1 1 0  0 1  40 0"
            >
         </path>
   </svg>




@Kane Li: sorry, I got the starting point wrong - in case you're using the path e.g as a motion path for animations. See updated answer and examples
